# Alias 403 Forbidden with Apache

Tags: apache, alias, directive, mod-alias

I'm trying to create a folder named week7 and an html page named hello.html in that folder outside the document root and have it viewed through an Alias directive.

I created a folder named week7 out of the Document Root.
I chose this location for it:

```
/usr/local/www/week7
```

while my document root is:

```
/usr/local/www/apache22/data
```

in httpd.conf and under  tag, I wrote:

```
    Alias /week7 /usr/local/www/week7
<Directory /usr/local/www/week7>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

After rebooting the server, I got the following message:
Forbidden 403 message.

I tried changing permissions for the hello.html file,
the week7 folder and even the www folder and nothing changed.

Any ideas?

Comment: `Require all granted` is AFAIK apache mod_authz in `Apache 2.4`. Are you one of the few running that? Most are still at `2.2`.

Comment: @Wrikken my server version is 2.2 but I used the command above from a tutorial on httpd.apache.org about Alias directive. I deleted the directory part and left my command looks like this:
  Alias /week7 /usr/local/www/week7
and restarted server and still nothing changed! (403 error).

Comment: Yes, you would still be not allowed. Removing a rule used in apache 2.4 to allow access doesn't make access rights magically appear in 2.2... You probably want `Order allow,deny<newline>Allow from all`.

Comment: You need to have the `Options` line. Without that, apache doesn't know where to apply these rules. So, add `Options Indexes` at least.

Answer (score 44):

If you're using apache 2.4

Order allow,deny
Allow from all

becomes...

Require all granted

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html

Comment: Ah, tricky thanks. I recently re-installed ubuntu on my dev machine and I guess 2.4 is the default.

Answer (score 30):

I know it's old but just for the record, the following worked for me in XAMPP (Windows 8)

```
Alias /projects c:/projects

<Directory c:/projects>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

### EDIT

On XAMPP 5.6 and Apache 2.4 try this:

```
Alias /projects c:/projects

<Directory c:/projects >
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Add `AllowOverride All` to make `.htaccess` files found in `/projects` work!

Comment: Brilliant practical solution. Allows  _xampp/htdocs_ to be retained as the **DocumentRoot** while allowing an external Eclipse project to be treated as an _htdocs_ subfolder.

Answer (score 8):

I fixed this issue with these directives:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Require local
```

You'll only be able to browse from your local computer, but it works for local testing and development.

Answer (score 7):

For me worked this solution:

When I access the virtual directory an error “Access forbidden! Error 403” occured. 
The config seems to ok:

```
Alias /static/ /home/username/sites/myblog/static/
<Directory /home/username/sites/myblog/static>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

**Solution**:
The default apache configration is very restrictive. It do not allow to access directories without authentication. This is defined in the Directory section of httpd.conf:

```
<Directory>
   AllowOverride none
   Require all denied
</Directory>
```

Add a “require all granted” directive to your virtual directory section will grant the access.

```
Alias /static/ /home/username/sites/myblog/static/
<Directory /home/username/sites/myblog/static>
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 5):

Trying the solutions offered by the other answers here, and finding they didn't work for me, using **Linux Mint**, I found another option to start apache as a different user.

After reading [unixd_module documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_unixd.html), I edited "httpd.conf" to change the `User` and `Group` to that of the owner of the `Alias` directory (or root user) and the 403 "Forbidden" error had gone.

1. Open your "httpd.conf" at `/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf` (in a default installation of XAMPP for example) in a text editor.
2. Find `<IfModule unixd_module>`, where the comments should read something like:

   > If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run httpd as root initially and it will switch.
   >
   > User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
   >
   > It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for running httpd, as with most system services.

   with the default `User` and `Group` set to `daemon`.
3. Edit the `User` and `Group`.

For example:

```
<IfModule unixd_module>
  User mrJohn
  Group mrJohn
</IfModule>
```

I hope this is useful.

Answer (score 1):

Alias /data /media/pi/VOLUME

.....

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

AllowOverride All

Require local

works fine on Raspbian for localhost

Answer (score 0):

I was able to gain access to a directory outside the document root, but using the method proposed in the original question to this thread.

```
   # Create Alias to access files for pure js front end app
   Alias "/hbt" "/dirA/dirB/dirC"

   # Create a Directory directive for "dirC"
   <Directory /dirA/dirB/dirC>
     Require all granted
   </Directory
```

Restarted Apache, and it worked! I'm using Apache 2.4